how to add solana metadata
I have recently minted my Solana tokens and sent them to my phantom wallet, but have not managed to add any metadata to my tokens, could anyone provide the latest way to achieve this as I have found many outdated methods?
spl-token initialize-metadata niceG6oxHmPcXVdNaUoECzWXn8Jz8fA5Q99QauJ4Gun
'Nice Token' 'NICE'
'https://bafybeidfm65jzvz4zeesxp6ybinkitvpd27klk6yspstrtw5fuy5w27lkq.ipfs.w3s.link/metadata.json'

